# Simpler way to limit entries in a .each() loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been wanting to know if there's a good, jQuery-esque way to do the following:

```
var count = 0;    

$("p").each(function() {
    if (count >= 5)
        return false;

    $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    count++;
});
```

Is there a similar function as `each()` in jQuery that will allow me to set a limit on how many items it'll loop over, or is this the best way of doing things?

Comment: You cannot declare a variable's type in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, bad habit left over from other languages.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question (since it has been answered), but for future reference the function passed to the each method can take a few parameters.  The first one is the current iteration of the each method.  Use that instead of keeping track with your own counter to clean up the code a bit ;p

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simplest thing is `.slice`:

```
$("p").slice(0, 5).toggleClass("highlight");
// only <p>s from index 0 (inclusive) to 5 (exclusive)
```

Comment: @Derek: You can slice arrays and strings, and jQuery also added support for jQuery objects.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/). This will split the array returned by `$("p")` for use with `.each()`:

```
$("p").slice(0, 4).each(function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

`.slice()` takes a start and end index as parameters. In the above example, we start from the first array element (index 0) and return the next 5 elements up to index 4.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply limit the elements selected: `$("p:lt(5)").toggleClass("highlight");`

Comment: +1 It's worth noting though that this cannot use the native selector engine.

Comment: I didn't look at the code, but sizzle might be smart enough to use a native query for `p` and then apply the filter - so it might be almost as fast as `.slice()`

Comment: I was just echoing the docs, I'm not sure what Sizzle actually does. http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/

Answer (score 2):

Will it work for you?

```
$("p").each(function(index){
 if (index >4)
 {
    return false;
 }
...
});
```

Comment: Also note that by returning `false` you can break out of the each early, thus avoiding unnecessary iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to write it is using `filter`:

```
$("p").filter(function(index) { return index < 5 }).toggleClass("highlight");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to repeat the loop a certain (known in advance) number of times. If the number of repetitions is not known, use a while loop (or each - an analogue from the functional programming)

So,

```
var i;

for (i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    $("p")[i].toggleClass("highlight");
}
```

Comment: If `$(p)` is supposed to be `$("p")`, I'm not so sure whether this is very performant. It might be better to select once.

Comment: @pimvdb This is a mistake. The selector should always be quoted (if it is not a variable, of course). Fixed.

Comment: To be honest, this piece of code is extremely bad: It performs a search for `p` elements in the document again in each loop. So it's very inefficient. Besides that, JS has a `++` operator so no need to use `+= 1`

Comment: @ThiefMaster It is example. You can replace the body of the loop on the comment "/ / do something" if you like. :) And I do not use the + + operator purposely, because from it more problems than good. Check [this page](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html).

Comment: It might be bad when used outside a `for()` loop head.. but inside that's pretty much what everyone uses (and yes i know, "what everyone does" could also be used to justify really bad things - but in this case it's true). And about "it is an example": Not all oeople are smart - some will just see it and copy it.